# ionic cordova run android failed

Tags: ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, angular6, uikit

An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: What you need as a result?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you show us which command you run in the terminal?